# Symfony2 + doctrine's query builder - where != 1

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a function that creates a query to my db, like this:

```
public function getList($u, $t, $ls, $lf) {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('
                    SELECT
                        o,
                        u,
                        g,
                        r,
                        t,
                        p
                    FROM GameShelfUsersBundle:Own o
                    LEFT JOIN o.user u
                    LEFT JOIN o.game g
                    LEFT JOIN o.rate r
                    LEFT JOIN o.typo t
                    LEFT JOIN o.platforms p
                    WHERE u.id = :user
                    AND o.typo = :type
                    ORDER BY o.updated DESC
                ')
            ->setParameters(array(
            'user' => $u,
            'type' => $t
            ))
            ->setMaxResults($lf)
            ->setFirstResult($ls)
            ->getResult();
    }
```

My problem is, how to set `:type` to be `not in`? I mean, I wanted to use it like this:

```
$type = '!= 1'
...
AND o.typo :type
...
'type' => $type
```

But it didn't worked at all. Using `$type = -1` doesn't help either. Is there any way, other than creating if/else statement and duplicating query?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a [query builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html)??

In that way you can easily customize your query, depending on some condition.

This is an example:

```
$q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('foo')
        ->select('foo')
        ->leftJoin('foo.bar', 'foobar')
        ->leftJoin('foobar.bar', 'foobarbar')
        ;
if($myVar > 0)
{
 $q->where('foobarbar.var = :myVar');
}
else
{
 $q->where('foobarbar.var = :staticValue');
} 
[...]
```

Remember to call `return $q->getResult();` at the end

Comment: While using my query, `query time` was 3.08 ms. While using the same query built with query builder, `query time` is over 9 ms. And that's only with dummy data.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski: if you want to create a query building it in a dynamic way, based on if...then...else statement (without duplicate piece of "code") this is the only way

Comment: PS.: You don't ask for a "speedest" way

Comment: I used ugly, but functional dupliace `query1 | query2` way mentioned by me earlier. Unfortunately, QueryBuilder is taking too much time (three times more), even if the code is more elegant and simple.

Comment: query1 | query2 will also mean that if you have another condition, in future, you'll have query3 and if you have to change something in your query, you have to replicate it along all of these. Think about it ;)

Comment: @TomekBuszewski moreover remeber that this "three time more", maybe, don't depend strictly on data quantity and so. Maybe is the little overhead of querybuilder itself. I mean, maybe this increment is a constat and large quantity of data retrieve will still be performing

Comment: No, no, that's all that is - only two queries, both executed at 0.9ms. And perhaps this is an overhead caused by querybuilder itself, I don't know and I can't tell, but when I do more tests (eg. when I'll fill my db a little more) I'll know which solution works best with performance.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski yes, but with small quantity of data, at least now, you can't evaluate in a good way :)